# ASP.NET conditional yes/no messagebox

Tags: asp.net, web, code-behind

I have an asp:Button that fires a code behind function on the OnClick event. In that OnClick event several things happen, and among those things I do a check in the database for if I need to ask the user a yes or no question. For that I need a message box. First I did it like this:

```
protected void MyButton_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // lots of stuff happening
    bool iNeedToAskTheUser = INeedToAskTheUser(stuff);
    if (iNeedToAskTheUser) 
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to fix all objects?", "Fix objects", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes) // do stuff
    }
    // some other stuff
}
```

This works fine locally but not when deployed, so I figure I would need to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript instead. I could just add javascript on the ASPX page that fires up a dialog and saves the response in a hidden control that I can then look at, but I don't want to fire up the dialog unless I have to, which I check for before I do the DialogResult in the code above. So I can't do that immediately when the user clicks the button.

Is there any way I can use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in "the middle" of my _OnClick code so that I can choose whether or not to actually show the button, and then also know if the user clicked yes or no, (preferably) without doing a postback?

Comment: "I could just add javascript on the ASPX page that fires up a dialog and saves the response in a hidden control that I can then look at, but I don't want to fire up the dialog unless I have to" ...so then either a) don't add the script at all if it's not required, or b) inject some boolean value into the JavaScript which is then used to control whether it goes ahead with displaying the dialog.  And yes you can use a registerstartupscript anywhere you like, as far as I know. Here's an example: https://www.telerik.com/forums/firing-javascript-function-after-postback

Comment: Another alternative to your approach is to call your server-side logic via AJAX, and then when you get the response back into your page, use JavaScript to read the response and decide whether or not to run some script to display the dialog. That way you avoid having to post the whole page back to the server.

Comment: You can also call Javascript OnClientClick and show a dialog if it is true, you can forward that to code behind or otherwise you can stay OnClientSide and display the dialog with whatever you want to display.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I can do it with an alert, but I need a yes/no dialog ("confirm") and I need to catch which button the user clicked and then go ahead and execute different parts of my code depending on the answer. So I need the code to wait for the user to choose a button in the popup dialog which I don't think RegisterStartupScript normally does, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @JawadAnwar Can you give me an example of how I, from my code behind, could call the JavaScript OnClientClick function to show a dialog depending on my bool iNeedToAskTheUser and then get the user reply and use it in my if case ("if (iNeedToAskTheUser)")?

Comment: RegisterStartupScript  can involve any script you choose. Literally all it does is inject the script into the page. What the script actually does is entirely your decision. People tend to give simple examples using "alert" because it's universal and easy to demonstrate, but there's no actual restriction on what script you can insert. You can inject anything that your target browser(s) are capable of executing.

Comment: @ADyson Sure, I get that. But do you have an example of a RegisterStartupScript that does a confirm and acts upon its result?

Comment: Forget the fact that it's injected via RegisterStartupScript. It's just some JavaScript. Like I said, RegisterStartupScript just puts the JS string into your web page. That's all it does. It's just an alternative to hard-coding it in your aspx file. You don't need anything special for it to work via this method. You can easily find JS libraries downloadable online which will provide this kind of dialog functionality. jQuery Confirm is one, off the top of my head (but requires jQuery of course), there are likely to be lots of others. I don't think I really need to google this on your behalf.

Comment: In fact if you want to keep it simple there's the bog-standard JS "confirm()" function. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp . Demo: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking and testing two different solutions:

1. Use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in code behind to fire a JavaScript confirm function on the ASPX page. The JavaScript function would set a value in a hidden control depending on if the user answered yes or no and then my code behind stuff would check the value of that hidden field and act upon that. The problem with that is that once ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript fires it doesn't wait for the JavaScript function to "finish", ie wait for the user to reply to the confirm(). So the value in the hidden control will always be empty because the code behind gets to the check of that control before the user has a chance to respond to the confirm(). So that's a no go.
2. Use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in code behind to open up a new ASPX page that asks the user the question and then does all the work in response to the user's answer in that page. The problem then is to pass the object that the new ASPX page needs to do work on in response to the user's response.

I'm sure there are great solutions using Ajax or jQuery but this is a fairly simple function that shouldn't take too long to develop, so that is kind of out of scope for this.

Instead I'll go with a solution where I know what the user will respond to the question before they click the button.  (While silently muttering under my breath: "It's 2019 and there's no good way to fire up a yes/no dialog from code behind in a .Net web project...". I need to get back to not working with web).